# With qemu-kvm VM, how to determine the number of `pcie-root-port` devices?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, pci

I use `qemu-kvm` on a DELL server  multi-core system with 64 cores 512GiB system to create virtual machines.

Using `libvirt` the `qemu-system-x86_64` command line features lots of `pcie-root-port` devices like this:

```
-device pcie-root-port,port=0x14,chassis=5,id=pci.5,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x4
```

I seek information and an answer to the question that allows me to determine how many such pcie-root-ports are necessary for the vm to run.

Does the number correlate with virtual pcie adapter cards or with pci-e channels (i.e. speed?). Or would it be dependent on the number and layout of virtual CPU cores given to the VM?